# body data request with application/octet-stream

Tags: http, curl, mime-types, content-type, iot

I have to do a request to a Daikin intelligent Touch Controller and i don't know how. Its documentation says that Content-Type should be "application/octet-stream". So i don't know how the request body should be. 
Here is a photo with an example in the documentation:

[image]

Probably if i can replicate this request i could continue by my own. I've been searching a lot with no results.

By the way i'm using cURL.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, they are instructing you to send binary data, with values as described in the hex dump and comments.

You would send the Content-Type line with a carriage return and newline terminator.

Then a blank line with just carriage return and newline.

And then raw binary data - in this case apparently 32 bytes to match the content length and the pictured hexdump.